# aliases for notes in lilypond

Tags: lilypond

```
\version "2.24.2"

{
\drums {
  \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #weinberg-drums-style
  tomfh
  }
}
```

Renders a floor tom using Weinberg Drums Style. Is it possible to assign aliases like in this pseudocode, so that I can use `ft` instead of `tomfh`, but otherwise keep using this style?

```
\version "2.24.2"

% pseudocode
ft = tomfh

{
\drums {
  \set DrumStaff.drumStyleTable = #weinberg-drums-style
  ft
  }
}
```

I found aliases for `/markup` in [the docs](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.25/Documentation/notation/ascii-aliases), but not for notes.

Comment: Great question! I'm using the same when writing for a 4-piece kit (the most standard for me when transcribing) with `th` for tom-high and `tl` for tom-low. I'm also happy to see that you are using the Weinberg notation! Didn't think many would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
drumPitchNames.ft = #'tomfh
```

Documentation [here](https://lilypond.org/doc/v2.24/Documentation/notation/common-notation-for-percussion.html#custom-percussion-staves)